# using @Qualifier in class constructor in scala

Tags: spring, scala

Can some one explain me this code section . This is a Scala code with spring.

```
class histoeyMaitanence(@Qualifier("Executionparam") Executionparam: mutable.Map([String, String]){
// rest of the code
}
```

I know that we can do the dependency injection by using @Autowire + @Qualifier in spring
something like this.

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("Executionparam") 
Executionparam: mutable.Map([String, String])
```

And please give a brief overview about the use of @Qualifier in spring.

Comment: Read about bean injection by name

Comment: I believe **Scala** and **Spring** do not play well together. Any reason for using both?

Comment: In my project I am using spark with Scala and spring framework for application development.